# SQL: Fetch rows with least date + Use CASE WHEN with select statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, greatest-n-per-group

I have a table with 3 columns (**id**, **type**, **date**) with following values:

```
id    type    date
---   ---      ---
191     0    2016-09-15 11:26:51.000
191     1    2016-09-15 11:30:31.000
200     0    2016-09-15 17:36:19.000
200     1    2016-09-15 18:26:51.000
331     0    2016-09-16 07:26:22.000
```

This is what I want to do:

For each ticketid above, select the row with least minimum date. Once that is done I want another column in my output called "isEngaged" which will be set to 1 if the ticketid has a type = 1 present for any of its records.

My desired output:

```
id    type    date                        isEngaged
---   ---      ---                         ---
191     0    2016-09-15 11:26:51.000        1
200     0    2016-09-15 17:36:19.000        1
331     0    2016-09-16 07:26:22.000        0
```

This is what I have so far: (this takes care of returning only the row with least date)

```
SELECT id, type, date FROM (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY date ASC) AS [Row], id, type, date)
      FROM mytable WHERE type IN (0)) WHERE [Row] = 1
```

Really not sure how to incorporate the isEngaged part. I tried to use CASE WHEN but not sure how to go forward with this:

```
SELECT id, type, date,
"isEngaged" = CASE WHEN (SELECT * FROM mytable where type in (1) and id = <not sure what to put here>) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
FROM mytable
```

If you know of a better way to do this then please let me know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you only accept `0/1` values in column `type` then you could use `MAX()` as a window function.

```
SELECT  
  id, type, date, isEngaged
FROM (
  SELECT
    id, type, date,
    MAX(type) OVER (PARTITION BY id) AS isEngaged
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY date) AS rn
  FROM mytable
  ) t
WHERE rn = 1
```

If you accept values higher than 1, then appropriate `CASE` statement within the `MAX()` would suffice:

```
SELECT  
  id, type, date, isEngaged
FROM (
  SELECT
    id, type, date,
    MAX(CASE WHEN type = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) OVER (PARTITION BY id) AS isEngaged
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY date) AS rn
  FROM mytable
  ) t
WHERE rn = 1
```

Comment: Thanks Kamil! Its working as expected. Instead of doing "WHERE rn = 1" how can I ask the query to select the row with the lowest rn without specifying "1"? Something like "WHERE rn = min(rn)"?

Comment: @90abyss lowest `rn` is 1. Don't try to complicate things :). This is the way [`row_number`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/ms186734(v=sql.110).aspx) works.

Comment: @90abyss you're probably doing it wrong but this seems to be a separate question. Try adding another window function and apply the condition in WHERE. If you are still in trouble, post your efforts as a different Q.

Comment: So I've another where condition at the end of your above query. If I have that filter in, the results returned often start with rn > 1. Therefore I was looking for another way where instead of rn = 1, we can do where rn is least.

Comment: You're right! I'll post it as a different question. Thanks for your help

Comment: Sorry I figured it out - After adding my filter inside the inner WHERE clause, everythings working fine. Thanks a lot, Kamil! :))

Comment: Great that you can solve things on your own. Keep improving :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
select
id,
case when sum_engaged > 0 then 1 else 0 end as isEngaged,
min_date
from
(SELECT id, 
sum(case when type IN( 1,3) then 1 else 0 end) as sum_engaged, min(date) as min_date 
FROM mytable 
group by id) g
```

Comment: Hey Beth - instead of using the sum(type) can you use something more generic. So currently I have types as only 0 and 1.. but tomorrow I may have 0,2,4 representing "0" and 1,3 for "1"

Comment: @Matt, it could be done in a single select, I don't know what else he needs to add.  I didn't think he'd have more than one target value from his example.